# Remover borda do botão

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Possuo um `Jumbotron btn` que não consigo tirar o `hover` do botão (o retangulo azul),
ja tentei desabilitar todos os styles no console do chrome porem não funciona.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">Entrar</button>

.jumbotron
{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 520,50 px;
    height: 687,50 px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.jumbotron .btn
{
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    background-image: url('images/bt_03.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    color: #bb4200;
    font-family: ubuntu;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: normal;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    border-bottom: 0px;
     border:none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
```

}

quando clico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, pode usar focus.

```
.jumbotron .btn:focus{
outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 0px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: 0px;
}
.jumbotron:focus {
 outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 0px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Clap Clap, funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a todos cada um ajudou um pouquinho.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima vejo nas respostas alguns dizendo para você usar `!important`. Alerta: Se você precisa usar o `!important` é por que algo em seu `css` não está tão correto como deveria. São raros os casos em que realmente um `!important` é necessário. Atente-se a isso.

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado!

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso:

```
.jumbotron:hover {
    border:none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}
```

Ficaria mais fácil se disponibilizasse o código do botão...

Comment: Editei a pergunta com mas um problema.

Comment: Tente isso 
.jumbotron::active {
    border:none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}
.jumbotron::actived {
    border:none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}

Comment: não funcionou..

Comment: Tente isso: 
.jumbotron .btn:actived
{
 border:none!important;
 background-color: white!important;
}

Comment: nada ainda amigo, adicionei mais informações na pergunta.

Comment: Ponha isso:
.btn:active{
    border:none!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso funcionou isto:

```
.jumbotron:focus{
  outline-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

o que tu pode fazer é sobreescrever a regra do hover com `!important`, algo do tipo:

```
#id:hover {border:none!important}
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta com mas um problema.

Comment: teria que ver a classe que fica o botão para te ajudar melhor... mas é só definir a classe e colocar o `border:none!important`

Comment: vou editar a pergunta novamente, mas a classe é btn

Comment: daí ou tu põe um id nele, e faz o link pelo id (#id), ou isso irá se aplicar a todos .btn

Comment: eu quero que aplique a todos,

Comment: então é só por `.btn {border:none!important}` tira a classe .jumbotron do seletor do css nessa parte

Comment: negativo, já tem esse codigo e não funciona

Comment: então manda o código aqui porque as informações não estão suficientes.

Comment: editei a pergunta chegou a ver?

Comment: teria que inspecionar quem é põe a borda e em qual elemento, pois se a borda estivesse no .btn, ela teria saído com a regra. (se ele for filho de .jumbotron como está no css)